# Installed Ubuntu with Wubi on Windows 7. When I'm booting up the computer, my keyboard won't respond and I can't switch to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, keyboard, wubi

After I installed Ubuntu with Wubi, I rebooted my computer and Ubuntu loaded up fine. I then restarted the computer to see if I could switch in to Windows, which I could. And then once again I tried restarting to get back in to Ubuntu, which is when I ran in to my problem. On the boot screen to select the OS, the computer wouldn't respond to my keyboard (Razer Deathstalker) and I couldn't choose Ubuntu, it just loaded Windows after time ran out. Is there any way to get my keyboard to work, or to force my computer to restart in to Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83286/why-cant-i-choose-ubuntu-at-boot/83287#83287

Answer (score 0):

Try a ps/2 keyboard, or a simple keyboard usb.